# Scrapy con Python en Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, vscode, scrapy

Hola a toda la comunidad!!
Me estoy formando en Python (DAW + Web Scraping). Actualmente estoy intentando ejecutar mi código pero, el problema que "veo" es que el .csv sale en blanco.
El código funciona (si no me equivoco) pero el problema es con el .csv. Agradezco de antemano toda la ayuda que puedan darme.

Gracias,
Cristian.

```
from scrapy.item import Field
from scrapy.item import Item
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

class Pregunta(Item):
    id = Field()
    pregunta = Field()
    descripcion = Field()
    

class StackoverflowSpider(Spider):
    name = "MiPrimerSpider"
    custom_settings = {
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'
    }
    
    url_semilla = ['https://stackoverflow.com/questions']

    def parse(self, response):
        selector = Selector(response)
        preguntas = selector.xpath('//div[@class="s-post-summary js-post-summary"]')
        i = 0
        for pregunta in preguntas:
            item = ItemLoader(Pregunta(), pregunta)
            item.add_xpath('pregunta', './/h3/a/text()')
            item.add_xpath('descripcion', './/div[@class="s-post-summary--content-excerpt"]/text()')
            item.add_value('id', i)
            i += 1
            
        
            yield item.load_item()
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

yo seguí este video y lo pude hacer :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L-9X9dRpJh0&ab_channel=AsperosGeek

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/350585)